# How to send a saved document to my gmail address

Tags: email

I have absolutely no idea how to use LinuxMint. So I don't understand any of the lingo or anything. I made a document in LibreOffice and saved it. I need to know, step by step how to send it my gmail account.I dont know what postfix or what anything else is.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make things hard, they are really easy.
Using firefox (or the browser you already used to post this question):

1. open a new tab, type: www.gmail.com
2. Sign in to your account
3. Click < Compose > at the email
4. Enter your destination email address
5. Chose attach, from the open dialog, chose < Home > from the left. You shall find the document you edited.
6. Then send.

Hope this solves the issue.